# How to filter LINQ query. Display results in ListBox control

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to filter a query based on user input into a text box and display results in the list box. I know it can be done but I can't seem to find the right direction. Here's and example of a query I'd like to filter:

```
var q2 = from o in db.Orders
                 orderby o.OrderDate descending
                 join c in db.Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                 select new { Customer = c.ContactName, orderDate = o.OrderDate, orderID = o.OrderID };
```

I'd like to be able to say filter the OrderID or say ContactName. I'm only learning so please be gentle but any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's a snapshot also to help if my explanation wasn't good enough.

[image: Filter using text box located in the search tab header.]

OK, I got this from Andrie! Its a start but not sure where to go in terms of actually filtering.

```
`var q2 = from o in db.Orders
                     orderby o.OrderDate descending
                     join c in db.Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                     select new { Customer = c.ContactName, orderDate = o.OrderDate, orderID = o.OrderID };

            if (tbxSearch.Text != null)
            {
                q2 = q2.Where();
            }

            lbxQ2.ItemsSource = q2;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `where` clause.

If you know from the input which field should be filtered (dynamic field filtering is a lot more complicated), you can do something along these lines:

```
var q2 = from o in db.Orders
             orderby o.OrderDate descending
             join c in db.Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
             select new { Customer = c.ContactName, orderDate = o.OrderDate, orderID = o.OrderID };

if (customer name filter is not empty)
{
    q2 = q2.Where(x => x.Customer == <customer name filter value>);
}

if (order id filter is not empty)
{
    q2 = q2.Where(x => x.OrderID == <order id filter value>);
}
```

Of course above is just a pseudo code to show the basic idea, you should actually apply filters based on your requirements.

Comment: Didn't quite understand so I elaborated by editing the question with your input. I want the content of the textbox to be the filter.

Comment: @RyanSpain, in what way do you want your input to be a filter? How would you know if user entered order id or a customer name or whatever else? Can you write a pseudocode (forget about linq, that's implementation detail) of how your system should work?

Comment: Basically, once the user edits the contents of the text box, some form of implementation checks to see if say the 'ContactName' field Contains any of the inputted text, perhaps using .Contains().

Comment: @RyanSpain, well, you already have everything you need. Use the examples above, but for filtering use something like `Where(customerName.Contains(input))`.